# Paste columns in several sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote the following code. It should loop through a selection of sheets and then add columns in each of the sheets.

```
  Sub test()

     Dim month As Variant
     Dim months As Variant
        months = Array("07 AMSTERDAM", "07 ARNHEM")

    For Each month In months

    Columns("L:L").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    range("L3").Value = "CALC"

    Columns("O:O").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    range("O3").Value = "CALC"


    Next month
 End Sub
```

When I run the code, however, it does add a column in each of the sheets of `months`, but it also adds the columns in the first tab (`07 AMSTERDAM`) twice.

Any thoughts on what's going wrong here and how I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't select the appropriate sheet.

```
  Sub test()

     Dim month As Variant
     Dim months As Variant
        months = Array("07 AMSTERDAM", "07 ARNHEM")

    For Each month In months
     Sheets(month).activate
    Columns("L:L").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    range("L3").Value = "CALC"

    Columns("O:O").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    range("O3").Value = "CALC"


    Next month
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looping over *string* values, not *worksheet* objects. Use the `Sheets` collection to select the proper worksheet based on name.

```
For Each month In months

    With Sheets(month)

        .Columns("L:L").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .range("L3").Value = "CALC"

        .Columns("O:O").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .range("O3").Value = "CALC"

    End With

Next
```